# Change color of text in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table in a View that I populate with JS code. 
I need to change color of all values where `<td class="speed">` more then `td class="speedlimit">`. How I can do this via JS?

```js
for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
  $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td class="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
    '<td class="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
    '<td class="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
    '<td class="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
    '<td class="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
}
```

```html
<table id="speedlimitTable" class="table table-striped cell-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Imei</th>
      <th class="text-center">Latitude</th>
      <th class="text-center">Longitude</th>
      <th class="text-center">Speed</th>
      <th class="text-center">Speed Limit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="speeddata" style="overflow-y:scroll" class="text-center"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You've asked so many questions about this project (and deleted most of them) I feel like SO should get a credit for actually doing it. Please show the actual HTML output, not the JS you use to populate the table content.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by below code:

Check the speed and speed limit before adding tr. I have added "danger" class when speed is more than speed limit.

```
for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) 
{
    if(speeddata[i].Speed > speeddata[i].speedlimits)
    {
        $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td class="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speed danger">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
    }
    else
    {
            $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td class="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve this by using the ternary opertor:

```
var speedlimitexceed = (speeddata[i].Speed > speeddata[i].speedlimits) ? "danger" : "";


for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) 
{
        $('#speeddata').append('<tr' + speedlimitexceed + '<td class="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speed danger">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
            '<td class="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');

}
```

Comment: You could DRY this up a lot.

Comment: yes, we can use the ternary operator, I am trying to optimize it and will update the optimize code soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and set the `<tr>` class with some css configuration:

```js
var speeddata = [
  { Imei: 'test1', Latitude2 : 100, Longitude2 : 200, Speed: 300, speedlimits: 300 },
  { Imei: 'test2',  Latitude2 : 110, Longitude2 : 210, Speed: 310, speedlimits: 300 },
  { Imei: 'test3',  Latitude2 : 170, Longitude2 : 250, Speed: 310, speedlimits: 340 },
]

for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
  $('#speeddata').append('<tr' +
  (speeddata[i].Speed > speeddata[i].speedlimits ? ' class="bigger" ' : '') +
  '><td class="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
    '<td class="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
    '<td class="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
    '<td class="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
    '<td class="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
}
```

```css
.bigger{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="speedlimitTable" class="table table-striped cell-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Imei</th>
      <th class="text-center">Latitude</th>
      <th class="text-center">Longitude</th>
      <th class="text-center">Speed</th>
      <th class="text-center">Speed Limit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="speeddata" style="overflow-y:scroll" class="text-center"></tbody>
</table>
```

---

Another option (depending on the case) is to search for the `<td>` you want after creating it using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) on `<tr>`.

To get the specified `<td>` you can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('#speeddata').find('tr').each(function(){
  if(($(this).find('td.speed').text()) > ($(this).find('td.speedlimit').text())){
    $(this).addClass('bigger');
  }
});
```

or even [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$('#speeddata').children('tr').each(function(){
  if(($(this).children('td.speed').text()) > ($(this).children('td.speedlimit').text())){
    $(this).addClass('bigger');
  }
});
```

*Note: To set `<tr>`class you can use [.attr('class', 'bigger')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) too, but it will remove all the other classes.*